# Adding an edge to the subgraph in BOOST GRAPH LIBRARY

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I use Boost Graph Library and I have created a Graph G and a couple of subgraphs, one of them is empty G'. Now I want incrementally, one by one, add an edge from Graph G to this empty subgraph. The problem is, I need to add a correspondent vertices at first in order to add an edge, f.e.,
Graph G is a triangle Graph: A<->B<->C<->A,
so I start with adding an edge A<->B to G', so I need at first add vertices A and B to G' and then it will automatically add an edge between them, as G' is a subgraph of G.
Then I want to add an edge B<->C to G', so I just need to add vertex C to G' and then it will automatically add an edge between B and C, BUT ALSO BETWEEN C AND A, AND THIS IS THE PROBLEM, BECAUSE I NEED IT ONLY IN THE NEXT ITERATION. Is it possible somehow to do it in right way? Thanks in advance, for the help!